# Importing Excel into Pandas with text in cell A1 - Transpose Problem

Tags: python, excel, pandas

If I take an Excel spreadsheet with text in cell A1 like this:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

And bring it into Pandas with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("sessions.xlsx")
```

Then in my Jupyter notebook it looks like this:

[image: Jupyter PD]

I then perform a transpose with:

```
df_t = df.T
```

Which then gives me this:

[image: Transposed PD]

My problem is that the column headers consist of the old row numbers as the index rather than "Mon", "Tue", "Wed" etc so when I am trying to address the columns to change formats etc I can't address them as I would like.

Using `header = None` in the pd.read_excel doesn't help.

I can go into the Excel spreadsheet first and delete the contents of cell A1 which then does work, but I want to be efficient and hands off on this.

Any suggestions to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can't visualize the problem. Can you please post some sample data?

Comment: By "old town numbers" do you mean "the row numbers from before the transpose"?

Comment: Read your data by specifying the index column: `df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=0)`

Comment: Jason, yes, sorry town - row, I have edited the original text.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the dataframe into a new dataframe from the second row and on, and name the column headers as the first row of the transposed dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("sessions.xlsx")
df_t = df.T

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df_t.values[1:], columns=df_t.iloc[0])
```

Result:

```
Sessions Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Avg Max
0          1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1          1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2          1   2   3   4   5   6   7
3          1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```